# magento subcategories in sidebar

Tags: magento, categories

I'm using Magento with an horizontal menu. This menu shows all parent categories. What I want is to show the subcategories of the clicked parent category.

How can i realise this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code in order to get sub-categories in the parent category page:

```
<?php
$parentCategory     = Mage::registry('current_category');
if($parentCategory){
    $catId              = $parentCategory->getId();
    $category           = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId);
    $childCategories    = $category->getChildrenCategories();
    foreach($childCategories as $_category){
        print_r($_category->getData());
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks

Comment: I remember that you should test, if a Category is active, as you get also the not active ones here. But not sure about it right now.

Comment: Yes Flyinmana is correct. You should filter if you don't want to show the inactive categories. Thanks